# External Database for login with ASP.NET User Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I uploaded my ASP.NET MVC site to the hosting platform https://my.gearhost.com, but I am unsure as to how I can enable user account functionality to the site.

I can access my MySQL Database through my site, which also hosted on gearhost with no trouble, but how do I make the DefaultConnection DB in ASP.NET external?

Upon going to the login page i receive this message:

"Use another service to log in.
There are no external authentication services configured. See this article for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services."

I tried going through the article, but it explains how to set up SMS and email Two-Factor Authentication. I am aware of the potential security issues regarding this, but this is for a simple school project.

This is the database in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZxEI.png

I'm sure there's an easy way to make this work, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your question.

You have a ConnectionString that you used for your local development which works locally, but once you deployed to your server it no longer works.

If this is the case you need to add the following to your **Web.Release.config** file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      connectionString="<ConnectionString from hosting provider>;"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Be sure to drop in the correct connection string.  This will be provided by your hosting provider.